# Mass mailer php or not

Tags: php, sendmail, massmail

Sorry for my Question but I'm too confused with all answers from stackoverflow!  I search all Topics of statckoverflow but I can not understand which is the best.  Some guys told that with php mailer (especial a PHPmailer class)  you can send 5000 mail without problem,and others advise programs.
So:

1. Is php the proper language for sending mass emails?  or  my server
   will be broken down in a minute?  I want to send  about 3000-4000++
   mails.
2. Can I call the "mail.php (script)" from my server that my site is on
   or this server will crashed and I will lost my site?
3. May I use a simple mass mailer  programm for this job?

Thank your for all your answers.

Comment: Your **IP** will be **BLACK LISTED**

Comment: 1. yes, 2.? 3.yes .. if you don't know what you are doing i suggest outsourcing this

Comment: it **may** be blacklisted, another good reason to outsource this if you don't know the ins and outs of mass emailing.

Comment: @Greg there are several reasons why your IP might get blacklisted. 1 If you send spam (or emails that look like spam even if they are not). 2. ISP's often only allow a certain rate of emails per hour from a single IP (you need to throttle your messages or the ISP might blacklist you for exceeding that limit). You also need to look at things like DKIM and SPF which can help ensure delivery of the message. At the end of the day it is often easier just to use a service who do that all for you. (Most of them have SMTP connectors, so you just change your SMTP details and you are up and running)

Answer (score 1):

PHP is fine for sending mass mails. The Mail/SMTP server is the bit that may struggle.

If you are sending 5000 emails, I would suggest looking at one of the mail delivery services out there. Most of them offer a free tier of service.

Mailjet, Sendgrid, MandrillApp are just a few off the top of my head.

Comment: mailchimp - never used but looks good

Comment: Mailchimp is a newsletter service. MandrillApp is the email delivery service from the same company.